# Как сделать разделитель на экране?

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 `Layout`,надо их разделить вертикальной чертой. Как эту черту сделать ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поместите оба элемента в `LinearLayout` c `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Между ними поместите вот такую вьюху-разделитель:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо Юрий  в который раз